# JProgressBar not displaying correctly from ActionEvent

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jprogressbar

In the below code the `JProgressBar` displays correctly when the `doSomething()` is called from within `main()` but not when called as a result of an `ActionEvent` - the interface seems to freeze. What is the problem?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;


public class ThreadedDialog  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{                
    private JDialog dlg;
    private JButton button;

    private void buildInterface(){
        button = new JButton("do stuff;");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button); 


        dlg = new JDialog(this, "Progress Dialog", true); 
        JProgressBar dpb = new JProgressBar(0, 500); 
        dlg.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, dpb); 
        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JLabel("Progress..."));         
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); 
        dlg.setSize(300, 75); 
        dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        dpb.setIndeterminate(true);        
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
            public void run() { 
                dlg.show(); 
            } 
        });                          
        t.start();     
        try { 
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
                System.out.println("wtf is going on here?");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        dlg.hide();         
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ThreadedDialog me = new ThreadedDialog();

        me.buildInterface();        
        me.pack();
        me.setVisible(true);
        me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        //me.doSomething();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637725

Comment: StackOverflowException gives you your solution (1+), but another problem I see is it appears you're trying to make Swing calls off of the EDT by showing the dialog in a thread that is background to the main Swing thread (again the EDT).  Don't do this.  I suggest that you read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you do with Swing components should be done on the event dispatch thread (EDT) (i.e. the thread used by Swing to call your events). You should launch threads to perform lengthy background operations.

In your code, you do the reverse : you try showing the dialog in another thread, and perform the long operation in the EDT.

Here's the fixed code :

```
package fr.free.jnizet.stackoverflow;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ThreadedDialog  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JDialog dlg;
    private JButton button;

    private void buildInterface(){
        button = new JButton("do stuff;");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);


        dlg = new JDialog(this, "Progress Dialog", true);
        JProgressBar dpb = new JProgressBar(0, 500);
        dlg.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, dpb);
        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JLabel("Progress..."));
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dlg.setSize(300, 75);
        dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        dpb.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        // create a thread for the background task
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
                        System.out.println("wtf is going on here?");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // when the background task is finished, hide the dialog in the EDT.
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dlg.setVisible(false);
                    }

                });
            }
        });
        t.start();

        // show the dialog in the EDT
        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create the GUI in the EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ThreadedDialog me = new ThreadedDialog();

                me.buildInterface();
                me.pack();
                me.setVisible(true);
                me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

You should read [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), and learn to use SwingWorker for background tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are doing dlg.show() on the new thread that blocks that thread and you have `Thread.sleep()` on your main thread so pretty much everything is blocked. Besides `JDialog.show()` and `hide()` are deprecated and you might want to be using `setVisible(true/false)`, but that was not causing any issue in your case. If you are trying to display a dialog with a progress bar for some time and then close it, here's the fixed code. There is a second thread now that takes care of hiding the dialog after some time leaving the main thread to do it's thing.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ThreadedDialog extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JDialog dlg;
    private JButton button;

    private void buildInterface() {
        button = new JButton("do stuff;");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);

        dlg = new JDialog(this, "Progress Dialog", true);
        JProgressBar dpb = new JProgressBar(0, 500);
        dlg.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, dpb);
        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JLabel("Progress..."));
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dlg.setSize(300, 75);
        dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        dpb.setIndeterminate(true);

    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dlg.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("wtf is going on here?");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dlg.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadedDialog me = new ThreadedDialog();

        me.buildInterface();
        me.pack();
        me.setVisible(true);
        me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // me.doSomething();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the cause of the problem, -1 for the solution. Code that changes the state of the GUI should execute on the EDT. So the setVisible(true) and setVisible(false) code should be wrapped in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). I would also think you only need a single Thread.

Comment: I figured, since the class was called ThreadedDialog, OP was experimenting with Threads and might want to keep it.

Comment: A special thread is needed for the background operation, but the dialog should not be made visible in a separate thread. Showing a dialog **must** be done in the EDT.